# Словообразование слов ОТТИСК и ШЕФСТВОВАТЬ

Tags: словообразование

От каких слов образованы слова *оттиск* и *шефствовать*? 
Например: морской -> море; захворать -> хворь.

Comment: Приведите свои варианты словообразовательного анализа этих слов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте данный вам ответ галочкой, если он оказался полезным.

Answer (score 1):

Словообразовательные цепочки:

- тис-к-а-ть -> от-тис-к-0 (приставочный способ);
- шеф-0 -> шеф-ств-о -> шеф-ств-ов-а-ть (суффиксальный способ).

Answer (score 1):

При словообразовательном анализе надо работать с толковым словарем:

1) ШЕФСТВОВАТЬ,  осуществлять шефство над кем-, чем-л. Поэтому **шеф/ство ― шеф/ств/ова/ть.** Суффиксальный способ образования.

2) ОТТИСК, 2. Отпечаток текста, рисунка и т.п., полученный типографским способом.

ТИСКАТЬ 3. (св. тиснуть). что. Типогр. **Отпечатывать** с помощью печатного пресса.

**Тиск/а/ть ― от/тиск.** Нулевой суффикс, префиксально-суффиксальный способ образования.